# How to create a method in a superclass that would return type Subclass

Tags: java

I'm pretty new to Java and it's safe to say I'm just taking my first steps. So I'm sorry if the question is a little awkward.
Basically I would like to know what would be the best approach to solving the issue I have.

I've got an abstract class `BasePage` and `HomePage` that is supposed to be derived from the former. All pages can be loaded, so it makes sense to define the load method on the `BasePage`, but I would like the method to return the type of HomePage in this case and SubClass type in general.

From what I've learnt , seems like it's not that easy and I started to think maybe it's because it's a flawed design.
I also have a few methods that are valid for all pages, one of them is `confirmAge`, cos no matter what page you go to, you're always greeted with the age gate and basically you have to confirm you're above 18 to proceed. So since it's something fundamental, I believe it should be coded into the `BasePage`.

Anyway, no matter what I use - abstract classes or interfaces, I have the same issue with return type and I would really like to enforce some interface on all the classes derived from `BasePage`.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: best way? not. a superclass is not supposed to know that the subclass exists, let alone what exact type(s) they are. You can just put a public ABSTRACT_TYPE getInstance() and add a cast to the actual type.

Comment: I think `Object::getClass` does what you require.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Simplest way addressing your use-case - relying on [covariant return types](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/Covariant-return-types-in-Java)

Example:

```
public abstract class BasePage {

    public abstract BasePage load();
}

public class HomePage extends BasePage {

    @Override
    public HomePage load() {
        //...
        return this;
    }
}
```

2. If you require also polymorphic arguments in addition to return types - make use of [generics](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/types.html)

Example:

```
public abstract class BasePage <T extends BasePage<T>> {

    public abstract T load();
    public abstract void copyFrom(T another);
}

public class HomePage extends BasePage<HomePage> {

    @Override
    public HomePage load() {
        //...
        return this;
    }

    @Override
    public void copyFrom(HomePage another) {
        //...
    }
}
```

Note, that second `<T>` in the generic definition can be omitted, giving a shorter

```
class BasePage <T extends BasePage>
```

and in this case, compiler will infer

```
class BasePage <T extends BasePage<?>>
```

which is still suitable for your general case

Comment: Sigh. Of course, covariant return types would be easiest. Don't forget the recursive bound in the generic case, though: `T extends BasePage<T>`.

Comment: Great answer. Thank you all!

Answer (score 2):

You can add the actual Type as a type parameter for the BasePage:

```
public abstract class BasePage<T extends BasePage<?>> {
    public abstract T load();
}


public class HomePage extends BasePage<HomePage> {

    @Override
    public HomePage load() {
        return new HomePage();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

One solution is to use generics:

```
public abstract class SuperClass<T extends SuperClass<T>> {
    protected abstract T someMethod();
}

public class SubClass extends SuperClass<SubClass> {
    protected SubClass someMethod() {
        return this;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Generics is best option here. You can T type interface here. Here is an example:

```
public interface Service<T> {
   T execute();
}

public class MyService implements Service<String> {

    private final String input1;
    private final int input2;

    public MyService(String input1, int input2) {
       this.input1 = input1;
       this.input2 = input2;
    }

    @Override
    public String execute() {
        return String.format("'%s%d'", input1, input2);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would design it like this: Create an abstract class `BaseClass` and leave the `loadPage` method unimplemented (abstract method). Now, whatever classes `extend` from `BaseClass` can have their own implementations of `loadPage`.

Or, write a basic `loadPage` method in the base class. This method should contain operation like making a `GET` request, that should be common to all classes whose objects require loading pages. Then, in the sub-classes of the base class, create some method like: `homePageLoader`. This method can call `pageLoader` in the base class to make `GET` requests.